# Expand Partition To Unallocated Space In Front Of The Partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, unallocated

I currently have Ubuntu installed on my hdd. However, somehow it sized itself to use only have of my hdd, and created its partition on the tail end of the disk. This leaves the other half unallocated and I can not expand into it.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Did you used to have Windows in the p2 partition?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 3):

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** the /dev/nvme0n1p3 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/nvme0n1p3 all the way to the right (or as far as you wish)
- click the Apply icon